# Campo date preecher com a data atual automaticamente

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Como eu configuro o mysql no phpmyadmin para que quando eu inserir um registro o campo `data_lancamento` automaticamente se preencher com a data atual sem eu precisar ficar passando a data pelo php, alguém sabe?

> Eu vi uma pergunta igual a minha [aqui](http://forum.wmonline.com.br/topic/227282-campo-do-tipo-datetime-do-mysql-duvida/), porem não obtive resposta
>   significativas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configure o `data_lancamento` para o tipo [TIMESTAMP](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/doc/refman/4.1/pt/datetime.html), e coloque no valor *Default* *CURRENT_TIMESTAMP*.

*Criação de Tabela exemplo:*

```
CREATE  TABLE `testdb`.`Exemplo` (    
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,    
  `data_lancamento` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,    
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
);
```

Essa solução é automática pelo próprio banco, mas, se você não quiser mudar e manter o `datetime` ou `date` é só colocar um `now()` em sua SQL assim:

```
INSERT INTO exemplo (data_lancamento) values (now());
```

Você também pode criar um [Trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)

```
CREATE TRIGGER `exemplotrigger` BEFORE INSERT ON  `exemplo` 
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.data_lancamento = NOW();
```

*Obs: Para `Date` ou `DateTime` não existe o mesmo recurso do tipo `TIMESTAMP`.*

*Referências:*

- [13.1.11 CREATE TRIGGER Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)
- [11.3.1 The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html)
- [6.2.2.2. Os Tipos DATETIME, DATE e TIMESTAMP](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/doc/refman/4.1/pt/datetime.html)

Comment: é isso mesmo, valeu mano ;)